# EF Core - fetch entities by composite key

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity with a composite key `{ A, B, C }` in my Postgres DB. In my application, I have a list of `Tuples` containing my composite key values and I'm trying to query the table to fetch all the database records whose composite keys are part of this list. By writing a pure SQL query, I could do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE (A, B, C) IN ( ('A', 1, 1), ('B', 1, 2), ('C', 2, 1) );
```

However, when I try doing it via EF Core `DbContext` I'm getting an exception that LINQ query couldn't be translated. This is the query I'm trying to execute:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int, int>> keys = // ...

var entities = dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(e => keys.Contains(new Tuple<string, int, int>(e.A, e.B, e.C)))
    .ToList();
```

What's the correct way to do this with EF Core 5.0.1 and .NET 5?

Comment: I don't think there is one.  You could always pass the keys as JSON in a raw SQL query and parse them on the server.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to concatenate bunch of `Union`'s:

```
IQueryable<MyTable> query = null;
foreach (var t in x)
{
    var interim = dbContext.MyTable.Where(mc => mc.A == t.Item1 && mc.B == t.Item2 && mc.C == t.Item3);
    query = query?.Union(interim) ?? interim;
}
var entities = query.ToList();
```

Also you can build [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) for `Where` clause:

```
Expression<Func<MyTable, Tuple<string, int, int>, bool>> sel = (mc, t) => mc.A == t.Item1 && mc.B == t.Item2 && mc.C == t.Item3;
Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> baseExpr = mc => false;
var resBody = baseExpr.Body;

var body = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(new[] {sel.Parameters[0]}, new[] {baseExpr.Parameters[0]}).Visit(sel.Body);
foreach (var tuple in x)
{
    var expression = new ReplacingExpressionVisitor(new[] {sel.Parameters[1]}, new[] {Expression.Constant(tuple)}).Visit(body);
    resBody = Expression.OrElse(resBody, expression);
}

var res = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyTable, bool>>(resBody, baseExpr.Parameters);
var entities = dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(res)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Guru Stron's answer, you can make the expression tree building part easier by using LinqKit's `PredicateBuilder`, with a modification of their nested ORs example [here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder).

```cs
var query = db.Foos;

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Foo>();
foreach (var compositeId in compositeIds)
{
    predicate.Or(e =>
        e.BarId == compositeId.BarId &&
        e.LolId == compositeId.LolId);
}

query = query.Where(predicate);
```