# EF Core Quotations - filter composite key by list of ids

Tags: entity-framework-core, f#, quotations

There is an entity that using composite key:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Entity =
  { Id1: int
    Id2: int
    Number: string }
```

I'd like to filter entities by list of ids tuple using `EF Core`. Ideally the produced query should use many wheres like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entities
WHERE 
    (Id1 = 1 AND Id2 = 1) OR
    (Id1 = 2 AND Id2 = 2) // etc.
```

According to [this EF issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30320) code below won't work:

```ml
let getMany(context: DbCtx) (ids: (int * int) array) =
  context
    .Entities
    .Where(fun ef ->
      Linq.Enumerable.Any(ids, fun (id1, id2) ->
        ef.Id1 = id1
        && ef.Id2 = id2))
    .ToListAsync()
```

Based on [answer from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138224/ef-core-fetch-entities-by-composite-key) I tried concatenate many where's but this produce many queries with single `where` combined by `UNION ALL`:

```ml
let getMany(context: DbCtx) (ids: (int * int) array) =
 ids
 |> Array.fold (fun (q: IQueryable<Entity>) (id1, id2) ->
     let predicate = context.Entities.Where(fun ef -> ef.Id1 = id1 && ef.Id2 = id2)
     if q = null then predicate else Queryable.Concat(q, predicate)
   ) null
 |> fun q -> q.ToListAsync()
```

Expression is an option but I'd like to use Quatation that is more F#-friendly. However I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've got a solution:

```
let getMany(context: DbCtx) (ids: (int * int) list) =
  let predicate =
    if ids = [] then
      <@ fun (_: Entity) -> true @>
    else
      ids
      |> List.map(fun (id1, id2) -> <@ fun ef -> ef.Id1 = id1 && ef.Id2 = id2 @>)
      |> List.reduce(fun expr1 expr2 -> <@ fun ef -> (%expr1) ef || (%expr2) ef @>)
          
  let q =
    query {
      for c in context.Entities do
        where ((%predicate) c)
    }
    
  q.ToListAsync()
```

The key thing is to use [query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions).